# Checking whether a SCons File Node is a Target Node of a Builder

Tags: build, dependencies, scons, build-system

In SCons, is it possible the check whether a File node, queried as `File(path)` is a target of a builder?

I want to use this in my Ada source code scanner to check whether a `path` refers to a node that has been, previously in the SConstruct/SConscript read phase, registered to be generated by a source code generation builder (also written by me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get that information with the [has_builder](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-api/SCons.Node.Node-class.html#has_builder) method of the Node object returned from `File()`.

```
File(path).has_builder()
```

Comment: `env.File(path)`, where path is relative to top, goes into source tree and not into variant (build) tree (where my generated code is placed) in my scanner. How do I make `env.File(path)` go into `VariantDir` instead? I'm looking for the reverse of `Node.srcnode()`, that is.

Comment: This sounds like a new question.  Could you create a new post, with a minimal example if possible?